# Random variable, randomness

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable

This is a theoretical question. When we say a random variable has a probability distribution, it implies a shape. Thus it is not truly random. Mathematically speaking, any single value is random but a long run of values has to confirm to a given distribution.

Is calling such process a random variable an appropriate label?

What is the difference between RV and Brownian motion?

Comment: It seems like you are assuming the draws are dependent, in that the next draw has to (or is more likely to) land in, say, the left tail given that we've had a lot of data from the right. That is intuitive, but it isn't the way we generally think bout these things.

Comment: No, which is why I said any single draw (next value)  is truly random. But any sufficiently large number of draws is predictable. Therefore, it is only random from the point of view of next value.

Comment: I was referring to the comment that "a long run of values has to confirm to a given distribution". If the draws are independent, then they don't 'have to conform to a given distribution' (although they are likely to *tend to*).

Comment: Then we are in agreement. I wonder if Brownian motion is classified as random variable

Comment: (i) You seem to be using the phrase "truly random" in an unconventional way. Please define this term. (ii) "Brownian motion" isn't a variable, but a class of processes. An observation on a Brownian motion process at a particular time, $W_t$ is an example of a random variable (though you could define many others in respect of some process).

Comment: You confuse a random variable and the (single) realisation of a random variable. And a Brownian motion is a single draw of a functional random variable, so I do not see the point in the question.